# What are neko_vm_custom() and neko_vm_set_custom() for?

Tags: c, haxe

I am embedding Neko VM into my desktop application. I did a lot of searching, but I am still unable to find out any helpful information regarding these 2 functions, which are declared in the `neko_vm.h`:

```
void *neko_vm_custom( neko_vm *vm, vkind k );
void neko_vm_set_custom( neko_vm *vm, vkind k, void *v );
```

What are these functions for?

#### Update 1

Got some response [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haxelang/nJbxtwtS2js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `neko_vm_set_custom` you can attach a custom variable (a context for example) of a user defined kind to your Neko virtual machine.

With `neko_vm_custom` you get that variable of that kind back.

An example might be: you have one or more VMs running, which are connected to their databases. With `neko_vm_set_custom` you attach the database connection for specific VM and with `neko_vm_custom` you can get it back.